# e.target.value is undefined while adding dynamic input data in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to add an input box (input-0, input-1...) each time a button is clicked.Following is the relevant code.

// State

```
      this.state = {
        newText: {}
      };
```

// Code to add dynamic input text

```
      addInputText = () => {
        let dynamicTextsNo = Object.keys(this.state.newText).length;
        let newInputId = dynamicTextsNo+1;
        let dynamicTextArr = this.state.newText;
        let newTextId = 'input-'+dynamicTextsNo;
        dynamicTextArr[newTextId] = '';
        let newState = { ...this.state, newText: dynamicTextArr }
        this.setState( newState );
      }
```

// Code to render dynamic input text.

```
      dynamicTextArea = () => {
        return Object.keys(this.state.newText).map( ( key ) => {
          return  ( <InputGroup key={key} borderType='underline'>
                      <Input placeholder='Type your text here' value={this.state.newText[key]} onChange={this.changeInput}/>
                    </InputGroup>
                  );
        });
      }
```

// Render function

```
      render() {
        return <View>{this.dynamicTextArea()}</View>
      }
```

// handle input

```
  changeInput = (e) => {
    console.log( e.target.value ); // **this comes out to be undefined.**
  }
```

Why is e.target.value in changeInput function undefined?

P.S. Jsfiddle link of the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/johnnash03/9by9qyct/1/

Comment: Could you upload your code to JSFiddle.net please? That would make it so much easier to help you debug your issue.

Comment: @KennyMeyer I have provided the link of the full code

Comment: @johndoe, I adapted your code to: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/gk55wLx1/ . But there is no error at changeInput. Check console.

Comment: @johndoe adapted version with persisted values at the inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/gk55wLx1/4/

Answer (score 11):

Unlike with the browser text input element, the `event` argument passed to React Native `TextInput.onChange` callback does not have a property called `target`.

Instead, use

```
<TextInput
  onChange={(event) => event.nativeEvent.text}
/>
```

or

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => text}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `bind` like so `<Input placeholder='Type your text here' value={this.state.newText[key]} onChange={this.changeInput.bind(this)}/>`

Comment: Still getting undefined after bind.

Comment: It would throw an error if it was not in bind anyways.