# value is NaN after parseInt() in react-native TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set an Int value from the `state` inside a `<TextInput>` by first turning it into `string` (`<TextInput>` can only receive a string) and then I want to be able to change the value and update the state value with the new `<TextInput/>` value. When I am trying to change the value inside the `<TextInput/>`

I get error:
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.keys.toString')`

UPDATE:

I removed the `this` from `this.keyInt` and now I receive `NaN` on input update , the error is gone though

React-Native code:

```
class Counter extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        keys: 0,
        id: this.props.id
     };
}


updateKeysWithInputHandler = (e) => {
    keyInt = parseInt(e.target.value);
    console.log(`keyInt is: ${keyInt}`);
    this.setState({
        keys: keyInt
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
                id={this.props.id}
                style={styles.title}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                maxLength={2}
                value={this.state.keys.toString()}
                onChange={this.updateKeysWithInputHandler}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed my problem thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864441/e-target-value-is-undefined-while-adding-dynamic-input-data-in-react) post and the help from [Adam Azad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151050/adam-azad) which point me to my problem.

apparently react-native `<TextInput/>` dont use `target` and instead its use `nativeEvent.text` so I changed my code and it worked now.

Working code:

```
updateKeysWithInputHandler = (val) => {
    keyInt = parseInt(val);
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({
        keys: keyInt
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput 
                id={this.props.id}
                style={styles.title}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                maxLength={2}
                value={this.state.keys.toString()}
                onChange={(event) => this.updateKeysWithInputHandler(event.nativeEvent.text)}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
   keys: this.keyInt
   // ___^^^^^
})
```

Remove the `this` keyword because it changes the context from the current scope to `Counter` scope, where `keyInt` variable is not defined.

Comment: ok I did now when updating the `input` I receive `NaN` any suggestions?

Comment: @obiwankenoobi, try to print `e.target.value` without passing it through `parseInt`

Comment: i get `keyInt is: NaN`

Comment: `console.log(e.target.value)`

Comment: @obiwankenoobi, it must only output the value. Without `keyInt is:`. You did not change the code.

Comment: Now you need to need to check `TextInput.OnChange` method, and see how it calls your function. You need to identify where the reference to `e` is lost. A good start is to see what the value of `e` is by outputting it.

Comment: you mean `console.log(e)`? for some reason it wont output anything I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

Why `keys: this.keyInt`?

Shouldn't it be `keys: keyInt`?

Answer (score 0):

```
updateKeysWithInputHandler = (event) => {
 if (isNaN(event.target.value) || event.target.value.toString().length=== 
 0) {
    event.target.value = 0;
    }
 this.setState({
    keys: parseInt(event.target.value)
 })
}
```